# Why this 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array in PHP called $jsonRankings. It's an indexed array, each element contains some utf8 encoded HTML.

I load this array into another array that has some other data in it:

```
$sumArray['rankings'] = $jsonRankings;
```

I have done a print_r of this array and verified it contains only the data I need, index starting at 0.

My PHP file's output is this:

```
echo json_encode($sumArray);
```

Here's my javascript:

```
function getScores(){

var xmlhttp;
var jsonText;
var rowData;
var rowText;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

}
else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
    {
        jsonText = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(jsonText);

        rowData = parsedJSON.rankings;
        for(var index in rowData)
        {
            rowText += rowData[index];
        }
        document.getElementById('rows').innerHTML = rowText;
        document.getElementById('sessionName').innerHTML = parsedJSON.sessionName;
        document.getElementById('elapsedTime').innerHTML = "Elapsed Time: " + parsedJSON.elapsedTime;
        document.getElementById('remainingTime').innerHTML = "Remaining Time: " + parsedJSON.remainingTime;
        document.getElementById('lapsCompleted').innerHTML = "Laps Completed: " + parsedJSON.lapsCompleted;
        document.getElementById('flag').innerHTML = "Flag: " + parsedJSON.flag;
        document.getElementById('tickerMessage').innerHTML = parsedJSON.tickerMessage;
     }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "scoreboard.php?json=1", true);
xmlhttp.send();


    setTimeout(getScores, 1000);
}

getScores();
```

Basically this script runs once every second and updates a bunch of values on the page, including changing the content of a  (table body) tag, inserting whatever rows need to be there.

This all works perfectly except my table body always has "undefined" as the first line. I really don't get why.

Comment: You shouldn't abuse `innerHTML` like that. Use `textContent` instead

Comment: What does the JSON *actually* look like? You should be able to check it from your browser's network debug console.

Comment: How are you using `$.parseJSON`? Do you have `jQuery` on the page? If so, why on earth wouldn't you use jQuery to make the AJAX requests?

Comment: I realize it is ***easy*** to copy and paste scripts from the web. But please look them over. There is no reason to support IE5/6 is there? You just copied the xhr code from a tutorial from 2008?

Answer (score 3):

Break it down to the problem:

```
var rowText;         //undefined
rowText += "Hello";  //undefined + "Hello";
console.log(rowText);   //"undefined Hello"
```

If you set it to an empty string, the undefined issue will go away

```
var rowText = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `rowText` is `undefined`.

```
var rowText; // The variable exist but it's value is undefined until a proper value is given to it.

for(var index in rowData)
{
    rowText += rowData[index];
}
document.getElementById('rows').innerHTML = rowText;
```

If `rowData` is empty (you should dump the value of it to make sure) then `rowText` will be `undefined`.

It would make more sense to give it an initial value of the empty string, that should give you the empty string instead of `undefined`.

Also, take a look at [why you shouldn't use innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502238/why-is-it-suggested-to-avoid-innerhtml).

Answer (score 0):

You might have a function on rowData, so try to check with HasOwnProperty whether rowData has the property before adding to text:

```
    for(var index in rowData)
    {
        if(rowData.hasOwnProperty(index)){
            rowText += rowData[index];
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 for no explanation (`try this` does not explain what you did)