# JavaScript error on document.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I am not sure why, but the following stops my JavaScript from working.

I know it is not best practice to do this, But I have no idea where it is breaking.

JavaScript:

```
function loadmore(id) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var content;
            var x = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            alert('' + x.length);
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<div class="thumbnail">'
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<img src="' + x[i].main_image + '" alt="' + x[i].title + '" style="width:300px !important; height:150px; overflow:none;">';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<div class="caption">';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<h3>' + x[i].title + '</h3>';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<p>' + x[i].content;
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '</p>';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<p><a href="//russellharrower.com/' + x[i].url + '" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Read More</a></p>'
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '</div>';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '</div>';
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '</div>';


                id = x._id;
                //document.getElementById("content").innerHTML+=content;

            }
        }
    }


    //xmlhttp.responseText
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "search/json&qid=" + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: Ok, ignoring the code style... what error are you getting?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Not really an answer but you should take a look at [why innerHTML should be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502238/why-is-it-suggested-to-avoid-innerhtml). More related to the question: Which errors are appearing in your developer tools? And by the way, this would probably be much _easier for you_ if you'd be using jQuery, like you tagged the question as additionally to raw javascript.

Comment: @Dhaval js has asi, that semicolon wont make a difference.

Comment: can you post your json? Please do something like that; console.log(x)

Comment: You can not do "</p>" with innerHTML! You are not building a string.

Comment: It seems your code works as long as you have correspondant json

Comment: Russell, are you able to accept one of the answers below?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, the correct order of operations is:

1. `new XMLHttpRequest`
2. `.open()`
3. `.onreadystatechange =`
4. `.send()`

In some browsers, especially those that allow re-using the same object for multiple requests, calling `.open()` will clear your `.onreadystatechange` handler.

As an additional note, please DO NOT mix `.innerHTML` and `+=`. Here's how the browser sees it:

> ```
> document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">';
> ```
>
> Oh, there's a missing end tag, better add that in. `</div>` added automatically.
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<div class="thumbnail">'
> ```
>
> Oh, there's a missing end tag, better add that in. `</div>` added automatically.
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<img src="' + x[i].main_image + '" alt="' + x[i].title + '" style="width:300px !important; height:150px; overflow:none;">';
> ```
>
> Okay, added an image. Note that we are ***not*** inside the `<div><div>` you expect!
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<div class="caption">';
> ```
>
> Oh, there's a missing end tag, better add that in. `</div>` added automatically.
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<h3>' + x[i].title + '</h3>';
> ```
>
> Okay, added the `<h3>`. Still not in the `<div><div><div>` you think!
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<p>' + x[i].content;
> ```
>
> Missing `</p>` tag, need to add that in.
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '</p>';
> ```
>
> There was no `<p>` here... better add one to make this `</p>` valid. Empty paragraph added.
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<p><a href="//russellharrower.com/' + x[i].url + '" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Read More</a></p>'
> ```
>
> Okay, paragraph with link added.
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '</div>';
> ```
>
> Ah! I didn't have an open `<div>`! Better add one. Empty `<div>` added. (repeat x3)

Can you see how this step-by-step approach is leading to issues because it keeps on thinking that you're done and correcting your "bad" HTML accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

There are several minor changes that can be made to simplify this.  Try ...

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var build_html = [
  "<div>",
  "Content Here",
  "</div>"
  ].join("\n");
content.innerHTML = build_html;
```

Obviously, your HTML content is more robust than what I have here, but with this you aren't slamming the DOM over and over.

Comment: In short, `innerHTML` and `+=` do *not* mix.

Comment: I would certainly agree with that ... I'm not 100% sure they don't mix technically, but it is definitely a bad practice at best.

Comment: They do not mix technically. Every time you read from `innerHTML` it serialises the DOM to HTML. So you cannot write partial elements as the code in the question is trying to do.