# How do I write text in html and submit with onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue here. I want to create a text box which I have done.
But I want an onclick function too work with it. For example, If I were to type something in the text field and then clicked the 'click' button, I would want the text to appear on the white space of the site. Here is the current code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Worlds Story!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>The Worlds Story</h1>
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">
    Tell Your Story!
    </textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Voting to close since no code is provided, SO is not here to write code for free for random people, instead it's to help people who already have a partly working code but are stuck with a very specific problem to get it working. Feel free to come back after reading and **trying** something on your own.

Comment: ...or at least show the code that you already have to create the textbox.

Comment: Guess who is getting an auto-ban for xmas?

Comment: I'm sorry I am not able to add my code. I literally just signed up a few minutes ago and am not familiar with how this website works:<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">
Tell Your Story!
</textarea>

Comment: @JelzBellz Go to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to read about how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without JQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="inp"/>

    <p id="par">This is a paragraph.</p>

    <button id="btn1" onclick="document.getElementById('par').innerHTML =  document.getElementById('inp').value;">Change text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is an example in JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/weinerk/Ln73L2zp/

Comment: Notice that .innerHTML should be [avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502238/why-is-it-suggested-to-avoid-innerhtml) and I recommend attaching event listeners instead of using the onclick property but it's good that you have something to work with now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").append( $("#inp").val() );
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="inp"/>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did not down-vote but notice that this question is not tagged with the jQuery tag.

Comment: Down-voter, please add a comment explaining your vote so that this new user can understand what he must do to improve.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I think this answer needs more explanation. The code shown _is_ straightforward, but the OP is a beginner.